# Get and Post Google Calendar events on user from API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to viable a project, where users can view their Google Calendar slots, and create an event. To do that, I need to get read/write access to the user's calendar, which as far as I can see, there is no way to do that with the Google Calendar API, without users giving their credentials. Am I thinking wrong? Is there a way that users can log in once, and I could store their credentials to log in in the Google Calendar API whenever they use my app?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, as a simple method, how about using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? In the case of Web Apps, after the user authorizes the scopes by logging in to the Google account once, the users can access the Web Apps without authorization after 2nd access by logging in to the Google account. But, I cannot correctly imagine your situation. So, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.